# Filtering out rude words

Tags: c++

This program will filter the input by replacing matching bad words with "Bleep!". I'd like the code to be more concise and C++ style where possible. One thing that bugs me is the `was_bad` flag I think is needed to skip printing a word that has matched one of my bad words - if there was some better way to skip the rest of the `while` loop upon encountering a bad word so I don't print `Bleep! poop`, for instance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) 
{
    int i, was_bad = false;
    string input, bad[] = {"poop", "balls"};
    vector <string> badwords(bad, bad + sizeof(bad) / sizeof(string));

    while (cin >> input)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < badwords.size(); ++i)
            if (badwords[i] == input)
            {
                cout << "Bleep! ";
                was_bad = true;
                break;
            }

        if (!was_bad)
            cout << input << " ";

        was_bad = false;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One thing that did strike me was to use a ternary operator:

```
while (cin >> input)
{
    for (i = 0; i < badwords.size(); ++i)
        if (badwords[i] == input)
        {
            is_bad = true;
            break;
        }

    cout << (is_bad ? "Bleep! " : input + " ");

    is_bad = false;
}
```

Comment: so I *can't* say poop, but I *can* say POOP and pooop p00p I would recommend looking at c++11 regular expressions.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/regex/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are looking for is `continue`;

```
while (cin >> input)
{
    for (i = 0; i < badwords.size(); ++i)
        if (badwords[i] == input)
        {
            cout << "Bleep! ";
            continue;          // This starts the next iteration of the loop.
                               // ie we go back to the while loop and read the
                               // the next word (or attempt to do so).
        }

        cout << input << " ";
}
```

You can also improve your search. Rather than using `std::vector<std::string>` use a `std::set<std::string>`. Then a find will automatically do a \$O(\log n)\$ search of the data.

```
while (cin >> input)
{
    if (badwords.find(input) != badwords.end())
    {
        cout << "Bleep! ";
        continue;
    }

    cout << input << " ";
}
```

Now that we have the basic algorithm we can use some of the standard algorithms:

So now replace the main loop:

```
std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
               std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "),
               BadWordFilter(badwords));
```

Then you just need to define the `BadWordFilter`

```
struct BadWordFilter
{
     std::set<std::string> const&  badWordSet;
     BadWordFilter(std::set<std::string> const& badWordSet) : badWordSet(badWordSet) {}

     std::string operator()(std::string const& word) const
     {
         static std::string  badWord("Bleep!");

         return (badWordSet.find(word) == badWordSet.end())
                      ? word
                      : badWord;
     }
};
```

Comment: Hm, I tried `continue` intially but it didn't work, I think in this case it just skipped remaining code and started the next iteration of the `for` loop (as `i` may not have reached its limit yet), whereas `break` would terminate all future iterations of the `for` loop and thus fall back into the `while` loop?

Comment: @DesmondWolf: The problem with your code is the variable `was_bad` as this was set just before the break. Then when you do a break the loop is re-started but now the next word is also ignored because you did not reset `was_bad`. Just drop this variable and its use.

Comment: Insightful post, lots to learn! Thankyou.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of iterating over a vector I'd use `std::find()`.
Even better, instead of `std::vector` I'd use `std::set`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string bad[] = {"poop", "balls"};
    set<string> bad_words(bad, bad + sizeof(bad) / sizeof(string));

    string input;
    while(cin >> input)
    {
        if(bad_words.find(input)!=bad_words.end()){
            cout << "bleep! ";
        }
        else {
            cout << input << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer can be improved slightly by getting rid of the string array and using the initializer-list constructor for std::set directly:
`set<string> bad_words{"poop", "balls"};`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I'd use `std::set` to hold the list of bad words in a case like this. `std::set` is (at least normally) implemented as a balanced tree, with each node separately allocated. This tends to reduce locality of reference.

By contrast, a `vector` is always contiguously allocated, improving locality of reference so it's more cache-friendly (and also tending to reduce heap fragmentation, for whatever that may be worth).

That doesn't mean you should forego the wonders of standard algorithms though. Quite the contrary, standard algorithms will do the job quite nicely. Since you only care about the presence/absence of a word in the "set", you can use `std::binary_search` to check:

```
std::vector<std::string> bad(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(bad_file), 
                             std::istream_iterator<std::string>);

// You can remove this sort if you're sure the words are already sorted.
std::sort(bad.begin(), bad.end());

// process the data
std::replace_copy_if(
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(infile),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(outfile, " "),
    [&](std::string const &s) { 
        return std::binary_search(bad.begin(), bad.end(), s); 
    }, 
    "bleep");
```

If memory serves, `replace_copy_if` is new with C++11, but it's fairly easy to write your own if necessary. If you don't have that, chances are pretty good you won't have lambdas available either. In this case, you should be able to replace it with a suitable invocation using `std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd`, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader (personally, I'd at least consider a function object or something like `boost::bind` instead).